# how to make RandomForestClassifier faster?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am trying to implement bag of word model from [kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/c/word2vec-nlp-tutorial/details/part-1-for-beginners-bag-of-words) site with a twitter sentiments data which has around 1M raw. I already clean it but in last part when I applied my features vectors and sentiments to  Random Forest classifier it is taking so much time.here is my code...

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
forest = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 100,verbose=3)
forest = forest.fit( train_data_features, train["Sentiment"] )
```

train_data_features is 1048575x5000 sparse matrix.I tried to converted it into an array while doing it indicates a memory error.

Where am I doing wrong? Can someone suggest me some source or another way to do it faster?

Comment: you almost certainly don't need to do most of your work training on 1M rows each time. Here's a suggestion: fit()/predict()/score(on held-out test set) your problem training (fitting) on just 50,000 rows, randomly sampled from your 1M. Then do the same for 100,000 rows. Then 150,000 rows, etc. I bet you'll see test scores start to converge with at significantly fewer than 1M rows

Comment: Even if your problem does show performance improvement as you add data all the way up to 1M rows, the exercise above allows you to estimate how long it would take to run it for 1M rows. Then you know if its a "I need to run this overnight" issue or a "this takes a totally infeasible amount of time" issue. If it's a "run this overnight" issue, I still suggest doing most of your coding / iterating on a small sample of your data, then when you have your code as you want it and you want to rerun with all data, just rerun with all data overnight

Comment: last suggestion - 5000 columns is huge. try some of the approaches you'll find from googling "sklearn dimensionality reduction".

Comment: @MaxPower thank you for help.....it worked for me....

Answer (score 14):

Actually the solution is pretty straight forward: get strong machine and run it **in parallel**. By default RandomForestClassifier uses **a single thread**, but since it is an ensemble of completely independent models you can train each of these 100 tress in parallel. Just set

```
forest = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 100,verbose=3,n_jobs=-1)
```

to use all of your cores. You can also limit `max_depth` which will speed things up (in the end you will probably need this either way, since RF can overfit badly without any limitation on depth).