# RandomSearchCV super slow - troubleshooting performance enhancement

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, random-forest

I have been working on the below script for random forest classification and am running into some problems related to the performance of the randomized search - it's taking a very long time to complete & I wonder if there is either something I am doing wrong or something I could do better to make it faster.

Would anybody be able to suggest speed/performance improvements I could make?

Thanks in advance!

```py
forest_start_time = time.time()

model = RandomForestClassifier()
param_grid = {
    'bootstrap': [True, False],
    'max_depth': [80, 90, 100, 110],
    'max_features': [2, 3],
    'min_samples_leaf': [3, 4, 5],
    'min_samples_split': [8, 10, 12],
    'n_estimators': [200, 300, 500, 1000]
}

bestforest = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator = model, 
                                param_distributions = param_grid, 
                                cv = 3, n_iter = 10, 
                                n_jobs = available_processor_count)

bestforest.fit(train_features, train_labels.ravel())
forest_score = bestforest.score(test_features, test_labels.ravel())
print(forest_score)
forest_end_time = time.time()
forest_duration = forest_start_time-forest_end_time
```

Comment: Did you have a look at this questions and its answers? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43640546/how-to-make-randomforestclassifier-faster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to speed this up is to 1) reduce the features or/and use more CPU cores `n_jobs = -1`:

```py
bestforest = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator = model, 
                                param_distributions = param_grid, 
                                cv = 3, n_iter = 10, 
                                n_jobs = -1)
```