# RandomSearchCV is too slow when working on pipe

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, xgboost, feature-selection, hyperparameters

I'm testing the method of running feature selection with hyper parameters.

I'm running feature selection algorithm `SequentialFeatureSelection` with hyper parameters algorithm `RandomizedSearchCV` with `xgboost` model

I run the following code:

```
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from mlxtend.feature_selection import SequentialFeatureSelector
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV
import pandas as pd

def main():

    df = pd.read_csv("input.csv")
    x = df[['f1','f2','f3', 'f4', 'f5', 'f6','f7','f8']]
    y = df[['y']]
    model = XGBClassifier(n_jobs=-1)
    sfs = SequentialFeatureSelector(model, k_features="best", forward=True, floating=False, scoring="accuracy", cv=2, n_jobs=-1)
    params = {'xgboost__max_depth': [2, 4], 'sfs__k_features': [1, 4]}
    pipe = Pipeline([('sfs', sfs), ('xgboost', model)])
    randomized = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator=pipe, param_distributions=params,n_iter=2,cv=2,random_state=40,scoring='accuracy',refit=True,n_jobs=-1)
    res = randomized.fit(x.values,y.values)

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

The file `input.csv` has only 39 rows of data (not including the header):

```
f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,y
6,148,72,35,0,33.6,0.627,50,1
1,85,66,29,0,26.6,0.351,31,0
8,183,64,0,0,23.3,0.672,32,1
1,89,66,23,94,28.1,0.167,21,0
0,137,40,35,168,43.1,2.288,33,1
5,116,74,0,0,25.6,0.201,30,0
3,78,50,32,88,31.0,0.248,26,1
10,115,0,0,0,35.3,0.134,29,0
2,197,70,45,543,30.5,0.158,53,1
8,125,96,0,0,0.0,0.232,54,1
4,110,92,0,0,37.6,0.191,30,0
10,168,74,0,0,38.0,0.537,34,1
10,139,80,0,0,27.1,1.441,57,0
1,189,60,23,846,30.1,0.398,59,1
5,166,72,19,175,25.8,0.587,51,1
7,100,0,0,0,30.0,0.484,32,1
0,118,84,47,230,45.8,0.551,31,1
7,107,74,0,0,29.6,0.254,31,1
1,103,30,38,83,43.3,0.183,33,0
1,115,70,30,96,34.6,0.529,32,1
3,126,88,41,235,39.3,0.704,27,0
8,99,84,0,0,35.4,0.388,50,0
7,196,90,0,0,39.8,0.451,41,1
9,119,80,35,0,29.0,0.263,29,1
11,143,94,33,146,36.6,0.254,51,1
10,125,70,26,115,31.1,0.205,41,1
7,147,76,0,0,39.4,0.257,43,1
1,97,66,15,140,23.2,0.487,22,0
13,145,82,19,110,22.2,0.245,57,0
5,117,92,0,0,34.1,0.337,38,0
5,109,75,26,0,36.0,0.546,60,0
3,158,76,36,245,31.6,0.851,28,1
3,88,58,11,54,24.8,0.267,22,0
6,92,92,0,0,19.9,0.188,28,0
10,122,78,31,0,27.6,0.512,45,0
4,103,60,33,192,24.0,0.966,33,0
11,138,76,0,0,33.2,0.420,35,0
9,102,76,37,0,32.9,0.665,46,1
2,90,68,42,0,38.2,0.503,27,1
```

As you can see, the amount of data is too small, and there are small amount of parameters to optimize.

I checked the number of cpus:

```
lscpu
```

and I got:

```
CPU(s):              12
```

so 12 threads can be created and run in parallel

I checked this post:
[RandomSearchCV super slow - troubleshooting performance enhancement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56710187/randomsearchcv-super-slow-troubleshooting-performance-enhancement)

But I already use `n_jobs = -1`

So why it's run too slow ? (More than 15 minutes !!!)

Comment: One question, training one model (without cv) with the default hyperparameters, how long it takes to you? It should take only an instant.

Comment: I had previously thought setting n_jobs>1 for nested jobs was problematic; try setting either your feature selector or the random search to `n_jobs=1`.  However, trying your script and some variants just now on Colab, everything works fine, and takes a couple of seconds at most.  What version of sklearn are you using?  See also https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/10232

Comment: scikit-learn==0.24.1

Comment: I tried to set XGBClassifier and SequentialFeatureSelector with n_jobs = 1, but same results...